# Rewriting at the type level

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have the following proof state:

```
1 subgoals
U : Type
X : Ensemble U
Y : Ensemble U
f : U -> U
g : U -> U
pF : proof_dom_cod U X Y f
pG : proof_dom_cod U X Y g
fg : f = g
H : proof_dom_cod U X Y g = proof_dom_cod U X Y f
______________________________________(1/1)
createarrow U X Y f pF = createarrow U X Y g pG
```

So I want to

```
assert (pF = pG)
```

and then use proof irrelevance to prove that. Unfortunately, `pF = pG` is not valid because they have different types, even though I know the types to be the same because `H`. saying `rewrite H` or `rewrite H in pF` leads to a match failure, I assume because `in pF` refers to the value not the type.

Is there an equivalent to `rewrite` for types?

Here's the theorem I'm trying to complete (with all necessary definitions).

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.
Require Import Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.


Definition proof_dom_cod 
(U : Type) (X Y : Ensemble U) (f : U -> U) : Prop
    := forall x : U, In U X x -> In U Y (f x).

Inductive setarrow (U : Type) (X Y : Ensemble U) : Type
        :=
    | createarrow (f : U -> U) (proof : proof_dom_cod U X Y f).

Lemma eq_setarrow
    (U : Type) (X Y : Ensemble U) (f g : U -> U) (pF : proof_dom_cod U X Y f) (pG : proof_dom_cod U X Y g)
        : (f = g -> (createarrow U X Y f pF = createarrow U X Y g pG)).
    intros fg.
    assert (proof_dom_cod U X Y g = proof_dom_cod U X Y f).
        rewrite fg.
        trivial.
Qed.
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example? Maybe using collacoq?

Comment: @ejgallego I have added it to my question.

Comment: @ejgallego CollaCoq is giving me an error on the Coq.* imports.

Comment: Oh you may need to load the coq-arith package. We should implement package autoloading... See if this solves your question: https://x80.org/collacoq/ayofofepag.coq

Comment: The problem is that the standard rewrite tactic cannot generalize properly it seems, I don't really know as I use a different rewrite tactic.

Comment: Is the alternate one in a different standard library? What is it named?

Comment: Is the ssreflect rewrite tactic, coming in the math-comp library, see http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/ and https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00258384. With this package, the solution becomes: https://x80.org/collacoq/uluqicavul.coq

Comment: @ejgallego It'd be nice if you made an answer from your link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to the general question, but here `subst` does the work. The proof can be finished as follows:

```
subst f.
apply f_equal. apply proof_irrelevance.
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I think in fact your answer is to the general question.