# Equality for elements of sig type in Coq

Tags: coq, subtype

With a sig type defintion like:

```
Inductive A: Set := mkA : nat-> A.
Function getId (a: A) : nat := match a with mkA n => n end.
Function filter (a: A) : bool := if (beq_nat (getId a) 0) then true else false.
Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.
Definition subsetA : Set := { a : A | filter a }.
```

I try to prove its projection is injective:

```
Lemma projection_injective : 
  forall t1 t2: subsetA, proj1_sig t1 = proj1_sig t2 -> t1 = t2.
Proof.
 destruct t1.
 destruct t2.
 simpl.
 intros.
 rewrite -> H. (* <- stuck here *)
Abort.
```

At this point, Coq knows:

```
x : A
i : is_true (filter x)
x0 : A
i0 : is_true (filter x0)
H : x = x0
```

I tried some rewrite without success. For example, why can't I rewrite of `i` and `H` to give Coq a `i0`? May I ask what did I miss here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where you got stuck, your goal looked roughly like this:

```
exist x i = exist x0 i0
```

If the rewrite you typed were to succeed, you would have obtained the following goal:

```
exist x0 i = exist x0 i0
```

Here, you can see why Coq is complaining: rewriting would have yielded an ill-typed term. The problem is that the subterm `exist x0 i` is using `i` as a term of type `filter x0`, when it really has type `filter x`. To convince Coq that this is not a problem, you need to massage your goal a little bit before rewriting:

```
Lemma projection_injective : 
  forall t1 t2: subsetA, proj1_sig t1 = proj1_sig t2 -> t1 = t2.
Proof.
 destruct t1.
 destruct t2.
 simpl.
 intros.
 revert i. (* <- this is new *)
 rewrite -> H. (* and now the tactic succeeds *)
 intros i.
Abort.
```

Alternatively, you could use the `subst` tactic, which tries to remove all redundant variables in the context.  Here is a more compact version of the above script:

```
Lemma projection_injective :
  forall t1 t2: subsetA, proj1_sig t1 = proj1_sig t2 -> t1 = t2.
Proof.
  intros [x1 i1] [x2 i2]; simpl; intros e.
  subst.
Abort.
```

You might run into another issue afterwards: showing that any two terms of type `filter x0` are equal. In general, you would need the axiom of proof irrelevance to be able to show this; however, since `filter` is defined as an equality between two terms of a type with decidable equality, you can prove this property as a theorem (which the [Coq standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html) already does for you).

As a side note, the [mathcomp](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library already has a [generic lemma](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html#val_inj) that subsumes your property, called `val_inj`. Just to give you an example, this is how one might use it:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype.

Inductive A: Set := mkA : nat-> A.
Function getId (a: A) : nat := match a with mkA n => n end.
Function filter (a: A) : bool := if (Nat.eqb (getId a) 0) then true else false.
Definition subsetA : Set := { a : A | filter a }.

Lemma projection_injective :
  forall t1 t2: subsetA, proj1_sig t1 = proj1_sig t2 -> t1 = t2.
Proof.
  intros t1 t2.
  apply val_inj.
Qed.
```

Comment: For the first problem, `subst` is a tactic that is helpful when dependent types are involved (cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368767/rewriting-at-the-type-level/37378740#37378740)).